# jstree node not getting created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstree

I have created a very simple jstree.

On click of a link I am calling createNode() function. It does uses `create` function from the api to create a node.

It seems to be a common jquery problem that I am facing. Please let me know what is getting wrong.

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/juyMR/16/

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479715/programmatically-adding-child-nodes-to-a-jstree

Comment: Thanks. I have already seen these examples but I am not sure what is wrong in my example.

Comment: When you are trying to create a tree,I believe that you need to pass some attributes to the `$("#jsTreeDiv").jstree` method.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line to:

```
$("#jsTreeDiv").jstree("create_node",$('#linodeid1'),false,"new name",false,false);
```

This will add to the root:

```
function createNode() {
    $("#jsTreeDiv").jstree("create_node",$('#jsTreeDiv'),false,{ state: "leaf", data: "No rename!" },false,true);
}
```

You have to identify the parent of the node you want to add the new node too.